Maximize the area of self-intersection of a folded triangle
A triangle $\Delta ABC$ is folded in a way to maximize the area of self-intersection.
My basic questions:

How to find the folding?
Is it possible to draw the folding line by ruler and compass for any triangle (how to prove it: Yes or No)?

I was thinking about construction of a similar triangle with known folded line compared to $\Delta ABC$ but finally I am not still sure of solving the problem.
Any ideas are highly welcomed.

Have you tried the equilateral triangle case? What are your conclusions from that?

I think, the symmetry line of the equilateral triangle suits well. But what about other triangles in general?
